# How on click ExpandandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How to click on ExpandableListView items and open a new Activity?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You probably want to fire the click event on a **child** item. Do you? Please use Google when searching for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
// setOnChildClickListener listener for child row click
simpleExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        //get the group header using groupPosition);
        //get the child info using childPosition);
        //display it or do something with it
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Clicked on :: " + groupPosition
                + "/" + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
});

// setOnGroupClickListener listener for group heading click
simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
        //get the group header using groupPosition);
        //display it or do something with it
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Header index  :: " + groupPosition,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```